# Get IndexError with exec in Python

Tags: python, exec, index-error

I want change sign in if statement. When I use exec

```
def set_value(array, negation=False):
        equal = "!=" if negation else "=="
        for index1, row in enumerate(pattern_map):
            for index2, column in enumerate(row):   
                exec("if array {} column: kar_map[index1][index2]=1".format(equal))
```

I get IndexError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/charlie/Desktop/Projects/Python/karnaugh_map.py", line       234, in <module>
print(kar_map.map_filled)
File "/home/charlie/Desktop/Projects/Python/karnaugh_map.py", line   176, in map_filled
kar_map = self.__class__.filled_map_1(self.__table.count_variable, self.map_pattern, kar_map, variable)
File "/home/charlie/Desktop/Projects/Python/karnaugh_map.py", line 160, in filled_map_1
set_value("")
File "/home/charlie/Desktop/Projects/Python/karnaugh_map.py", line 148, in set_value
exec("if array {} column: kar_map[index1][index2]=1".format(equal))
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Map' object does not support indexing
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/bin/python3.5', '-u', '/home/charlie/Desktop/Projects/Python/karnaugh_map.py']]
[dir: /home/charlie/Desktop/Projects/Python]
[path:    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/opt/ope ncascade/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl]
```

When I don't use exec, it works.

```
def set_value(array, negation=False):
        for index1, row in enumerate(pattern_map): 
            for index2, column in enumerate(row):   
                if negation:
                    if array != column:
                        kar_map[index1][index2] = 1
                else:
                    if array == column:
                        kar_map[index1][index2] = 1
```

Anyone have any idea whats the problem?

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but why are you using `exec` instead of the non-exec code?

Comment: First off, please don't use exec in this way. It can be quite volatile and run into issues such as this. Could you post an example `pattern_map` and 'array' so we can debug locally.

Answer (score 1):

When using single-line if statements, you put the `if` part after the code you want to run. In addition, the `.format(equal)` doesn't make sense. What do you want equal to be? If you want to change the equals sign (=), you should use `.format(equals = equal)` and change `=` to `{equals}`. You should change

```
exec("if array {} column: kar_map[index1][index2]=1".format(equal))
```

to

```
exec("kar_map[index1][index2] {equals} 1 if array {} column".format('=' = equal))
```